# HTML5 error for main inside body

Tags: html, netbeans

My netbeans editor(ver 7.3.1) showing error: element "main" not allowed as child of element "body" in this context

To my understanding main tag is supposed to be within body tag. Is there something wrong with netbeans definition? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its currently a bug in netbeans -> https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242026

a possible solution could be the html5 metadata, where u add the specific tag...but i guess thats kind of tricky...